# google font how to find out which font has been used on a picture

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

i saw how to do this once somewhere i think [html5rocks](http://html5rocks.com) but now i can not figure out how to do it maybe there is someone out there who can help me on this.

i what to find out what Font they used on this picture and if it ist hostet on google font or where can i buy it

[image]

Comment: If i'm not wrong you can use the chrome developer tool to see the font name and the font file. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

Comment: you are correct but this is standard and this is not what i am looking for please note that the font is on a picture so no html

Comment: If the text is flattened with the image, the only way is to slice the text from the image and try some font recognition site. (but with this background it may be hard, you may need to mask it a little with photoshop in order the recognition  to go smoothly)

Comment: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ ist doing it but the result is very bad

Comment: if you are using chrome  right click anywhere on the page and click inspect element and you can see the css property

Comment: In Photoshop, you can use the selector tool to select all the white parts (i.e. the text) and then drag that to a part with a solid background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is called [Pacifico](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Pacifico)--I use it all the time.  You can do a search and find it.